# How do I exclude these .jar files? Error com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, appodeal

When I add this line:

```
compile project(':react-native-appodeal')
```

I get the error:

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/facebook/ads/AbstractAdListener.class

I know it is coming from `facebook-audience-network-4.12.1.jar`,

[image]

because I have another `facebook-audience-network` elsewhere in my project:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.18.+'
```

However when I try:

```
compile(project(':react-native-appodeal')) {
  exclude group: 'com.facebook.ads'
}
```

It does not clear the error. What am I missing?

**UPDATE: So there are two culprits.**

1) `facebook-audience-network-4.12.1.jar` and `javax.inject-1.jar`

How do I exclude these? I was able to get the project to build by simply removing them and clean, but if possible I would like to do something like:

```
compile (project(':react-native-appodeal')) {
  exclude group: 'com.facebook.ads'
  exclude (group:'javax.inject', module:'javax.inject')
}
```

^ didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You already have that class in your libs folder.
Remove all that dependency and try importing the module directly to work in JS class